# Python open() unicode filename behaviour different across OSes

Tags: python, unicode

With a filename looking like:

```
filename = u"/direc/tories/español.jpg"
```

And using open() as:

```
fp = open(filename, "rb")
```

This will correctly open the file on OSX (10.7), but on Ubuntu 11.04 the open() function will try to open `u"espa\xf1ol.jpg"`, and this will fail with an IOError.

Through the process of trying to fix this I've checked `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` on both systems, both are set to utf-8 (although Ubuntu reports uppercase, i.e. UTF-8, not sure if that is relevant). I've also set `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the python file, but I'm sure this only affects encoding within the file itself, not any external functions or how python deals with system resources. The file exists on both systems with the eñe correctly displayed.

The end question is: How do I open the `español.jpg` file on the Ubuntu system?

Edit:
The `español.jpg` string is actually coming out of a database via Django's ORM (ImageFileField), but by the time I'm dealing with it and seeing the difference in behaviour I have a single unicode string which is an absolute path to the file.

Comment: For what it's worth, `"\xf1"` is the ISO-8859-1 representation of `"ñ"`.

Comment: FYI, I touched a file named `español.jpg` and opened it using your way and it worked correctly on my Arch Linux. Could you paste your Ubuntu's `locale` output?

Comment: `locale` gives `en_US.UTF-8` for a number of parameters including `LANG`.

Comment: This isn't `"\xF1"` the byte string, it's `u"\xF1"` the Unicode string. That equals `u"ñ"` so the encoding of the source is correct. This works fine for me in Ubuntu. There is I suppose the possibility that the filesystem doesn't have the right encoding (eg if it is an NTFS partition mounted with the wrong options). What is the IOError you are getting, and what do you get if you `os.listdir('/direc/tories')` (byte string)?

Comment: The IOError is complaining that the filename that I'm looking for doesn't exist. If I run `os.listdir('/direc/tories')`, I get the list of files as string objects, with unicode characters printing in the two digit hex format (i.e. `\xf1`). Should it be loading these as unicode objects?

Answer (score 2):

This one below should work in both cases:

```
fp = open(filename.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()), "rb")
```

Comment: `sys.getfilesystemencoding` is a bit of a lie: on many platforms (I'm looking at you, UNIX), the filesystem does not have an encoding, but is just bytes. The applications—not the filesystem—define the encodings used to represent filenames, if the filenames are text at all.

Comment: This wouldn't work on Windows because `getfilesystemencoding` doesn't actually report the file system encoding (UTF-16). Don't ever do this if you want to be platform-independent.

Comment: But I am getting `mbcs` on windows using `getfilesystemencoding`, which handles Windows's file system correctly.

Comment: @FelixYan: It doesn't handle filenames that contain characters outside the ANSI code page.

Comment: dan04 is right. The only reliable way to access filenames under Windows is using a Unicode string, due to Python's specific support for sending them direct to the Win32 API. (Most other languages use the C standard library functions, which use the ANSI APIs, and consequently cannot work with filenames whose characters don't fit in the current locale's ANSI code page.)

Comment: @dan04 I was using a Windows XP Chinese version, which actually uses `gbk` as file system encoding. If I want to read a file which has Chinese characters in its name, either I use `UTF-16` to encode, or just pass unicode strings, they both fail in errors(file not found, etc), but `mbcs` in such times are equal to `gbk` and handles correctly. What's wrong with this? Is Chinese version of Windows that different?

Comment: What's wrong with this is that it's perfectly legal for you to have files named in Spanish or Russian or Hebrew, that contain characters that aren't in GBK, and you can't open those files with the ANSI API.

Comment: @dan04 Thanks, I think I got the idea. But how can I fit my program in both cases? i.e. open file named with CJK characters AND other characters, both works well?

Comment: In a C(++) program, on Windows, you have to use the "Unicode" (i.e., UTF-16) version of everything, like `int wmain(int, wchar_t**)` instead of `int main(int, char**)` and `_wfopen` instead of `fopen`.  OTOH, *nix is the opposite, supporting UTF-8 well but not UTF-16.  Makes it a pain to write cross-platform code.

Comment: In Python, however, you can just use Unicode strings everywhere.  On Windows, they'll be passed to the OS API as-is, and on *nix, they'll be converted to the locale's encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to simply set the file encoding at the top of your file. Make sure that your editor is using the same encoding, and saving the text in that encoding. If necessary, re-type any non-ascii characters to ensure that your editor is doing the right thing.

If your value is coming from e.g. a database, you will still need to ensure that nowhere along the line is being encoded as non-unicode.

Comment: Sorry, should've added the edit information in from the start which I think should probably negate in-editor encoding issues...?

Comment: @mrmagooey: Yes, but note that you still need to make sure that you're not encoding the string in a different way somewhere along the line.